# Angular material library slider doesn't render visibly

Tags: angularjs, slider, angular-material

Scripts and CSS loaded in the header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-C6CB9UYIS9UJeqinPHWTHVqh/E1uhG5Twh+Y5qFQmYg="
        crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
```

ng-Material is loaded into the app:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'ngMaterial']);
```

Using the slider in the html template:

```
<md-slider min="0" max="7" ng-model="rate" aria-label="rate" id="rateSlider"></md-slider>
```

The associated controller:

```
app.controller('theController', ['$scope', "$state", 'uiHandler', function ($scope, $state, uiHandler) {
    var handler = new uiHandler($scope, "html/content/theTemplate.html", true);

    $scope.showMenu = true;
    $scope.percentBid = 2.3;
    $scope.topRate = 6;
    $scope.rate = 3.2;
}]);
```

The control appears to render in HTML but none of the elements are actually visible. I can click on them in the page inspector, but I don't think any CSS styles have been properly applied.

Answer (score 0):

[Angular Material](https://github.com/angular/material) depends on several modules:

- `angular` (obviously)
- `angular-animate`
- `angular-aria`

Your example lacks the last one. Try including this line:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.js"></script>
```

See the simplified [Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/6DUN6jraNgTMqq4dhMQ7?p=preview).

Comment: I wish that was it. I was actually loading aria, but from my own server using "base.js" But I have fixed this to use the DSN, but still it doesn't work

Comment: @GeeWhizBang Could you also create a minimal example in the aforementioned Plunker?